# List on left border when position is set to outside

Tags: css, html-lists

I am trying to align the left side of my list with the border of the document (same vertical position as the title element).

Note: Since I want a set space between the numbers and the actual content, I chose to use `list-style-position: outside`.

HTML:

```
<h1>My Title</h1>
<ol>
    <li>first list element</li>
    <li>second list element</li>
    <li>third list element</li>
</ol>
```

CSS:

```
ul, ol {
    line-height: 17pt;
    list-style-position: outside;
}

ul {
    list-style: square;
}

ol {
    list-style-type: decimal;
}

ul > li, ol > li {
    padding-left: 5mm;
}
```

What it currently does:

[image: what it does]

What I want it to do:

[image: what I want]

Comment: control margin-left of the ol

Comment: the numbers begin to vary in width when you get to ten, so just setting a margin-left doesn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible when you use `list-style-position: outside`. See this example https://jsfiddle.net/obpm5qrc/12/

I'm not sure if you can alter your HTML but the use of `list-style-position: inside` and an extra span with padding would fix your issue.